# How to get a subset of fields from Entity Framework from a join with a field that has the same name as the table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am learning Entity Framework and Linq at the same time. I can get a table to a grid with this

```
List<object> boel;

var query = from BillingOrderEntries boe in DM.BillingOrderEntries
    select boe;

boel = query.ToList();
dataGridView1.DataSource = boel;
```

But I am having difficulty trying to get a subset of fields between two tables.  I think the join is right because I've looked at several examples.

```
var boel = new[] { new { DateOfBirth= default(DateTime?), FirstName = "", LastName = "", AccessionField = "", Requisition = "" } }.ToList();

var query = from a in DM.Accessions
    join boe in DM.BillingOrderEntries on a.Accession1 equals boe.Accession
    orderby boe.LastName
    select new { boe.DateOfBirth, boe.FirstName, boe.LastName, a.Accession, a.Requisition }

boel = query.ToList();
dataGridView1.DataSource = boel;
```

The problem was the `Accession` table had an `Accession` column in it. I tried changing the name of the class to `AccessionTable`, then modifying the property to reflect this in the context class but either this cant be done or I missed something somewhere. I then changed the property in the `Accession` class to `AccessionField`. It compiled but won't run:

> The specified type member 'AccessionField' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

I can't change the database, but I can change any code that would make this work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alias for a field in the select clause as shown below, note this example just mocks the classes you're referencing to mimic your code and demonstrate how to select clause aliasing:

**UPDATED**

```
    /* Mock class */
    public class Accession
    {
        [Column("Accession")]
        public string AccessionField { get; set; }
        public string Requisition { get; set; }
    }

    /* Mock class */
    public class Billing
    {
        public string Accession { get; set; }
        public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    /* Mock class */
    public class DataManager
    {
        public IEnumerable<Accession> Accessions { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Billing> BillingOrderEntries { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        /* Start: Generate fake data */
        DataManager DM = new DataManager();
        DM.Accessions = new List<Accession>() { new Accession { AccessionField = "a1", Requisition="r1" }, new Accession { AccessionField = "a2", Requisition = "r2" } };
        DM.BillingOrderEntries = new List<Billing>() { new Billing { Accession = "a1", DateOfBirth = "01-01-2016", FirstName = "first1", LastName="last1" }, new Billing { Accession = "a2", DateOfBirth = "02-02-2016", FirstName = "first2", LastName = "last2" } };
        /* End: Generate fake data */

        var query = from a in DM.Accessions
                    join boe in DM.BillingOrderEntries on a.AccessionField equals boe.Accession
                    orderby boe.LastName
                    select new {
                        boe.DateOfBirth,
                        boe.FirstName,
                        boe.LastName,
                        a.AccessionField,
                        a.Requisition
                    };

        var boel = query.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: your structure does not match the problem.  I have a field with the same name as the table.  That is what I need to know how to fix.

Comment: How can I change my structure to match the problem? Can you update your question's code to clarify?

Comment: Change public class Access to public class Accession

Comment: @John I've updated the code to use [Data Annotations](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/column-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)  for this scenario where the table name has a column with the same name

Comment: Tried that, it does not work.  Colunm is not recognized and the object browser brings back dozens.

Comment: This Entity Framework has too many shortcommings. I am going to abandon this approach.

Comment: @John Sorry, I tried but without more details I cannot make good recommendations, best of luck