# EF Core How to Create Generic Navigation Properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, generics, relationship

I'm utilizing EF Core and Identity Framework in my project, and within the AppUser extended from IdentityUser, I have various navigation properties for types like `Post` and `Comment`. These types are extends from base classes such as `PostBase` and `CommentBase`. Each of these subclasses contains one or more navigation properties related to the AppUser class, with relationships differing as one-to-one, one-to-many, and many-to-many.

Instead of creating separate navigation properties for each subclass within the AppUser class, how can I handle this structure as generic? I'm uncertain about potential errors in transitioning to a generic structure within EF Core. Additionally, I'm seeking guidance on applying Fluent API for these relationships mappings. Particularly, I'm unsure about best practices and considerations when using proxies and lazy loading in EF Core, and I could use some assistance in this aspect.

---

Important Code Snippets:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
   public virtual IEnumerable<FlowPost> FlowPosts { get; protected set; } = default!;
   public virtual IEnumerable<PersonalPost> PersonalPosts { get; protected set; } = default!;
   public virtual IEnumerable<StoryPost> StoryPosts { get; protected set; } = default!;

   public virtual IEnumerable<FlowPostComment> FlowPostComments { get; protected set; } = default!;
   public virtual IEnumerable<PersonalPostComment> PersonalPostComments { get; protected set; } = default!;
   public virtual IEnumerable<StoryPostComment> StoryPostComments { get; protected set; } = default!;
}

public class FlowPost : PostBase<FlowPostComment>
{        
}

public class PostBase<TComment> : ModifiableEntityBase, IPost 
   where TComment : class, IComment
{
   protected PostBase(Guid id, Guid createdById, PostType type, string description) : base(id, createdById)
      => (Type, Description) = (type, description);

   public PostType Type { get; protected set; }
   public string? VideoPath { get; protected set; }
   public string? ImagePath { get; protected set; }
   public string? SoundPath { get; protected set; }
   public string Description { get; protected set; }

   public virtual IEnumerable<TComment> Comments { get; protected set; }

   public virtual IEnumerable<AppUser> LikedUsers { get; protected set; }

   public static PostBase<TComment> CreateVideoPost(Guid id, Guid createdById, string description, string videoPath)
      => new(id, createdById, PostType.Video, description)
         {
            VideoPath = videoPath,
         };

   public static PostBase<TComment> CreateImagePost(Guid id, Guid createdById, string description, string imagePath, string? soundPath = null)
      => new(id, createdById, PostType.Image, description)
         {
            ImagePath = imagePath,
            SoundPath = soundPath
         };

   public static PostBase<TComment> CreateSoundPost(Guid id, Guid createdById, string description, string soundPath)
      => new(id, createdById, PostType.Sound, description)
         {
            SoundPath = soundPath,
         };

   public static PostBase<TComment> CreateTextPost(Guid id, Guid createdById, string description)
      => new(id, createdById, PostType.Text, description);
}
```

Comment: Entity create a mapping that links the c# classes/properties to a database table/fields.  I do not know what happens when you send only a subset of properties c# to database.  I think retrieving data is simple (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297949/how-to-get-a-subset-of-fields-from-entity-framework-from-a-join-with-a-field-tha), but saving in database you may get a lot of nulls.  I think table splitting may be the answer : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/429560/how-should-design-my-entities-when-i-sometimes-need-only-a-subset-of-fields

Comment: Hi @samiayaz, The `FlowPostComment ` should be define like:`public class FlowPostComment : IComment`, and the AppUser should contain the property like:    `public virtual IEnumerable<PostBase<IComment>> Posts { get; protected set; } = default!;`. Configure the fluent api like: `modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>().HasMany(u => u.Posts).WithOne().HasForeignKey(p => p.CreatedById);`.  Regarding proxies and lazy loading,  you can use the `UseLazyLoadingProxies` method when configuring your DbContext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you *should **not*** add navigation properties from the `AppUser` back to each of the tables that has what is effectively Audit information. It is not needed in *most* cases, but it is also prohibitive when you implement generic structures like this.

`FlowPost` can still have a reference to `AppUser` but you do not need the reciprocal link back. This means you will have to query `FlowPost` table if you want *all* posts by a user, but that is not a bad thing, it is a few extra lines of code and you have to think about it for a second but you should be thinking about it before you load *all* records into memory. It is too dangerous to allow `AppUser` references to *include* `FlowPosts` and other related tables like that by default when the times when you would actually need all that data are very limited compared to the times that an `AppUser` will be loaded from the database.

Fluent API:

```
modelbuilder.Entity<FlowPost>()
.HasOne(p => p.CreatedBy)
.WithMany()
.HasForeignKey("CreatedByUserId");
```

- You will find that Attribute notation will be easier to implement for generic structures like this, otherwise you will need to manually create the fluent configuration or use T4 or other code generation techniques to do this for you.

Notice we use `.WithMany()` but do not specify a collection navigation property, that way your `AppUser` is not coupled to these *generic* tables, you can create any arbitrary number of tables and will not have to append references to `AppUser` either manually or via code generation techniques.

As a general rule / best practice, I would encourage you to NEVER lazy load any relationship. Lazy loading is, lazy programming. It works for proof of concept and small applications but can lead to performance and memory issues as you scale or evolve your application. You should instead write more prescriptive projections when you need them.